# Jquery CSS manipulation

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the css attribute of a div on hover like

```
$(function(){
$("div#box").hover({
$("div#box").css({z-index:'12'});
});
});
```

Dreamweaver is giving me a syntax error. Can anyone please tell what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$(function(){
    $("div#box").hover(function(){
        //hover on
        $("div#box").css({zIndex:'12'});
    },
    function(){
        //hover off
        $("div#box").css({zIndex:''});
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZtLLg/

Comment: thanks that works perfectly.I hope it is same for attributes such as borderBottom for border-bottom ?

Answer (score 3):

1. At the beginning, I think you want `$(`, not `$.(`.
2. At the end of the second line, I think you want another nested function: `.hover(function(){` instead of `.hover({`. As it is, you're creating an object literal, which I don't think is what you want.

Comment: $(function(){
$("div#box").hover(function(){
$("div#box").css({'z-index','12'});
});
});


It still giving syntax error on the .css line

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(function(){
$("div#box").hover(function(){
$("div#box").css('z-index', '12');
});
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: The `css` call shouldn't need to be changed -- it can take a map (object literal).

Comment: @JoeWhite - I think it needs to be a string. http://jsfiddle.net/jvkjF/1/ (`{zIndex:12}` works though, http://jsfiddle.net/jvkjF/2/)

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right about it needing a string (because of the hyphen in `z-index`). I only noticed that you had changed it from the map overload to the two-strings overload -- I missed the bit where you had also put quotes around the `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

Altogether, I have just commented how to use animation and  classes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div#box').hover(
      function(){
        $("div#box").css({zIndex:'12'});
        //$(this).find('img').animate({opacity: ".6"}, 300);        
        //$(this).find('.caption').animate({top:"-85px"}, 300);
        //$(this).removeClass().addClass("someClassName");          
      }, 
      function(){
        $("div#box").css({zIndex:''});
        //$(this).find('img').animate({opacity: "1.0"}, 300);                   
        //$(this).find('.caption').animate({top:"85px"}, 100);
        //$(this).removeClass().addClass("someClassName");          
      }     
      );
});
```